# Pritunl server running on Azure VM - VPN clients have no internet

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, vpn-client

I have a Pritunl VPN Server running on an Azure VM (ubuntu).

For testing purposes, I used the default configuration which routes all traffic through the VPN tunnel. My clients *(some desktop pc's and some VPN travel routers)* all connect successfully, can talk to each other, and have internet access.

I now want to stop routing client internet traffic through the VPN, but continue to route local traffic. I removed the default "0.0.0.0/0" route per the documentation. My clients can still connect and talk to each other, but none of the clients/device can access the internet.

It seems that with this configuration, DNS is not getting resolved and I'm not sure if it's a Pritunl issue, a client issue or even an issue with my VM's network configuration.

This is all pretty new to me, I'm not even sure where to begin debugging this and hope someone can help.

**Other findings:**

- Using the official Pritunl client for windows, I **DO** have internet access.
  *(OpenVPN Connect and other ovpn clients do not work though)*
- This same
  setup works well with OpenVPN Cloud Server *(Pritunl Server is part of
  the spec though)*
- Ping result to google: "*Ping request could not find host google.com*"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved this, I'm not sure if it's the correct solution, but it does work...

According to the Pritunl Docs here: [Internal DNS or VPC DNS Server](https://docs.pritunl.com/docs/internal-dns)

When connected to the VPN, DNS queries still go through the VPN tunnel and are denied when they come from other networks. To solve this, create a /32 route to the VPC's DNS server and specify this as the DNS server for VPN clients to use.

Instead, I created a /32 route to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8 and set these as my client dns servers.

All of my requirements are now met.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the DNS Server value in pritunl would work too

Comment: This worked for me